# Rails 3.2.11 select box "selected" issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, forms

This is perhaps the strangest issue I've ever run across using Rails:

In the process of creating a form select that displays values from 1 - 100% (but saves in the db as fractional numbers) like so (which works fine, showing "93%" selected):

```
<%= f.select(:foobar, ((1..100).map {|i| [i.to_s + "%",(i*0.01)] }),{:selected => 0.93}) %>
```

I discovered a bizarre issue with the 'selected' value: the values 0.94 and 0.95 CANNOT BE PRE-SELECTED IN MY APP. As in, this DOESN'T work:

```
<%= f.select(:foobar, ((1..100).map {|i| [i.to_s + "%",(i*0.01)] }),{:selected => 0.94}) %>
```

The selected value was originally a db value (of course), but in the debugging process I removed everything else, and hardcoded the values. 0.94 & 0.95 ALWAYS default to .01 (the first value in the group). The values can be selected manually, and saved to the db with no problem. They just can't be pre-selected. I even removed the select and placed it in another form in my app, adding an attr_accessor. Same issue. Every other value behaves perfectly.

Does anyone have any idea what might be going on here, or will I just have to go insane on this one? :)

Comment: I've currently punted and used whole integer values, although it's not optimal for my purposes. Still very strange.